# Javascript parse all day date YYYY-MM-DD in my timezone

Tags: javascript, date, datetime

Suppose I create an all day event for Christmas day. I want this event to be 25 Dec regardless of which timezone you are in. I store the event date as "2023-12-25" on the server.

When I do `new Date("2023-12-25")` in the browser it's interpreted as a UTC date which is not what I want, for example if I'm in New York and I do

```
new Date("2023-12-25") // Sun Dec 24 2023 19:00:00 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)
```

Which means when I go to format the all day event it will format as 24 December which is not what I want.

Desired behaviour:

```
// If in New York
parseAllDayDate("2023-12-25") // Sun Dec 25 2023 00:00:00 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)

// If in London
parseAllDayDate("2023-12-25") // Mon Dec 25 2023 00:00:00 GMT+0000 (Greenwich Mean Time)
```

Also, please don't suggest dayjs or momentjs I would like to do this just with JS Date.

Comment: The calls to *Number* in the last line are redundant, `return new Date(year, month - 1, day)` is sufficient.

Comment: Oh the wonders of javascript @RobG of course `"02" - 1 === 1`

Comment: Sure, but when the [*Date* constructor](https://262.ecma-international.org/#sec-date) is called with two or more arguments, then *ToNumber* is called on each argument, so doing it manually is, literally, redundant. ;-)

Answer (score -2):

You can try this

```js
parseAllDayDate(dateString) {
    let dateStringSplit = dateString.split('-');
    let date = new Date();
    date.setUTCDate(dateStringSplit[2]);
    date.setUTCMonth(dateStringSplit[1]);
    date.setUTCFullYear(dateStringSplit[0]);
    return date;
}
```

Comment: Mixing local and UTC methods as in this answer is fraught and bound to introduce errors, e.g. mock running this on 28 Feb and pass it a date for 31 Jan.